# Lock and unlock users based on inactivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am implementing the ability to lock and unlock users using the isLockedOut property based on the amount of time that is has been since the last time they logged in.

**Use case:**

User attempts to log into the system and is has been more then the amount of time you are allowed to go without being authenticated on the system. (35 days) They do not get logged in and are told they are locked out and must contact the admin.

The admin goes into the system and unlocks the user. The user should be able to return to the login screen and log in.

**My approach:**

I have the login page compare the lastloginDate of the asp_membership table to the current date and if the difference is more then the allotted time(35 days) the user is locked out using a stored procedure I wrote.

I have the ability for an admin to log in and unlock a user.

**The issue:**

After a user has been inactive, gets locked out, then gets unlocked they should be able to log in. By with my approach they immediately get locked out again because when the user is unlocked they the lastLoginDate is not changed.

I want to avoid changing the lastLoginDate when they are unlocked because the field should only be changed on log in. The only other solution I can think of is to create another table which I would really like to avoid as well.

Any solutions?

**Note:** I realize I have not included code because it doesn't seem needed. I am just looking for a solution not for a block of code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you looked at LastLockoutDate? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastlockoutdate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RickS How would I use that? This is independent of when they were last locked out.

Comment: If the LastLockout date > lastLoginDate and isLockedOut = false, then they were unlocked and let them back in?  Just spitball'in here.

Comment: I see what your saying... I could change the way I check to see if I should lock the user out. And check to see if the use has been locked since the lastLoginDate + the timeout time, and if that is true and the user currently is not locked, allow for the log in controller to attempt the verification. That's creative, I was hoping I was missing something like this. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @RickS it turns out that the last lockoutdate is rest to 1754-01-01 when unlock is called. So I am going to have to write a new stored procedure to unlock the account without resting the timestamp.

Comment: I used this site http://www.adivo.com/samples/database/aspnetdb/PR-ASPNETDB-aspnet_Membership_UnlockUser.htm, and modified it so that it wont reset the last lock out time.